# Looking to check if string contains date using JS

Tags: javascript

I am looking to check if a string contains a date in format `MM/DD/YYYY`, and then if it does convert it to `YYYYMMDD000000`

```
var date = "test->1/22/2022";
```

if date contains `MM/DD/YYYY`
then set date from `MM/DD/YYYY` to `YYYYMMDD000000`

How would you do this?

Comment: Are you looking for `MM/DD/YYYY`, `YYYY-MM-DD` and/or `MM-DD-YYYY`?

Comment: Please show your attempt. What is the problem you bump into?

Comment: I would like to use MM/DD/YYYY to YYYYMMDD000000 @RocketHazmat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be simple, you could use `split`.

```js
var date = "test->1/22/2022";
let arr = date.split('->')[1].split('/')
console.log(arr[2]+arr[0]+arr[1]+"0".repeat(6))
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for [Regular Expressions](https://xkcd.com/208/)!

```
date.matchAll(/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/g);
```

Then you can use the `Date` object to convert it however you like:

```js
let date = "test->1/22/2022",
    matches = date.matchAll(/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/g);

for (let val of matches) {
    let valDate = new Date(val[0]),
        month = valDate.getMonth() + 1,
        day = valDate.getDate(),
        dateStr = ''
            + valDate.getFullYear()
            + (month < 10 ? '0' + month : month)
            + (day < 10 ? '0' + day : day)
            + '000000';
        
    console.log(dateStr);
}
```